# How to complete "Fortress in the Swamp" puzzle in Thronebreaker?

Tags: thronebreaker-the-witcher-tales

*Fortress in the Swamp* is a puzzle in *Thronebreaker* which requires you to kill all enemy units with Meve's lethal ability. Is there only one way of completing this puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one solution for this puzzle from the [gamepressure guide](https://guides.gamepressure.com/thronebreaker-the-witcher-tales/guide.asp?ID=47326#NH3_5), and found another solution myself.

**Solution 1**

> 1. Play Forager in the melee row.
> 2. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row on the right from Forager, deal 2 damage to a Recruit. Kill Recruit with Meve.
> 3. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row on the right from Forager, deal 3 damage to the Inexperienced General. Kill Inexperienced General with Meve.
> 4. Play Mantlet in the melee row, target Lyrian Arbalest.
> 5. Play Mantlet in the melee row, target Lyrian Arbalest.
> 6. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General. Kill another Recruit with Meve.
> 7. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General.
> 8. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General.
> 9. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General. Activate Forager's order. Kill Recruit with Meve.
> 10. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General.
> 11. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General.

**Solution 2**

> 1. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, deal 1 damage to Inexperienced General.
> 2. Play Mantlet in the melee row, target Lyrian Arbalest.
> 3. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, deal 3 damage to Inexperienced General. Kill Inexperienced General with Meve.
> 4. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, deal 4 damage to Inexperienced General. Kill Inexperienced General with Meve.
> 5. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, deal 5 damage to Inexperienced General.
> 6. Play Mantlet in the melee row, target another Lyrian Arbalest next to the Lyrian Arbalest you have previously targeted.
> 7. Play Forager in the melee row to the left of targeted Lyrian Arbalests. Activate Forager's order.
> 8. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, deal 4 damage to Inexperienced General. Kill Inexperienced General with Meve.
> 9. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General.
> 10. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General.
> 11. Play Lyrian Arbalest in the melee row, kill Inexperienced General.